# Cassandra: How to perform upsert in lightweight transaction

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, upsert

In Cassandra, I want to add a row, and if it already exists, only update it if the existing date is earlier than the new date. This is how it's done:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (...) VALUES (...) IF NOT EXISTS;
```

If the first query is not applied, I'm running this second one:

```
UPDATE tbl SET ...
WHERE ...
IF date <= ?;
```

Is it possible to merge the two queries into one? Maybe using the UPDATE as an upsert, while keeping the IF condition. We are having performance issues with these statements (timeouts) so this is the reason why I want to change it.

Regular updates (without IFs) also perform inserts if the row doesn't exist, but the lightweight transaction doesn't. Maybe it's possible to "trick" it into inserting as well.

Thanks!

Comment: How can the update condition `date <= ?` be true in case the row doesn't exist?

Comment: I was thinking maybe there's a way to "tell" it to do the update if the row doesn't exist; something like IF date <= ? OR NOT EXISTS; since I already checked I know it doesn't do that by default

Comment: Theres no guarantee the row hasn't been created between executing the first insert and following update. You really need to use a single LWT statement for atomicity.

Comment: I'm trying to use a single statement, but I don't know how to achieve that. I only know about batches, that simulate a transaction...but I would prefer reducing it to one statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LWT is basically doing a check before executing data mutation. Conditional execution is enabled only for INSERT and UPDATE with these conditions:
1. IF NOT EXISTS for INSERT
2. IF column = 'value' for UPDATE

You cannot mix and match these conditions with different operations. If there was an option to say UPDATE ... IF column <= 'value' it would have to hit all the nodes and propose a transaction to all of them and this would be a huge performance impact. LWT impacts performance even with equals conditions by hitting only replica nodes.